# How can I filter pages from Facebook’s Graph API by a specific category?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to fetch from Facebook's Graph API pages which belong to a specific category.

Currently I'm using this URL call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=42.21,20.7&distance=5000&access_token=&fields=id,link,name,cover,category,category_list,location,likes
```

How could I filter specific categories which are found in the **category_list** so I only get pages that belong to those categories?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you couldn't filter by **category_list**, but you can do something similar with the **categories** parameter. 
You just need to add the **categories** parameter to the end of your link, and set the q parameter (with that, you can search for the name of the place, but you can set it to *). For me it returned an empty object without the q parameter, but you may worth to try without that.
So, your search will look like this, if you would like to search for places with categories named food & beverage:

> *graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=42.21,20.7&distance=5000&access_token=&fields=id,link,name,cover,category,category_list,location,likes&categories=["FOOD_BEVERAGE"]&q=**

For more information about the parameters and the possible values of the categories parameter, read the Graph API search documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/search